# What does 入れこみ mean here?

Tags: meaning

I saw a short sentence: “A入れこみB”. What does this mean?

A enters B? B holds A? Or A says something to B? Or does it mean something else?

I found this sentence in a storyboard, looking a bit like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a shortened storyboard action description rather than a real sentence, something like that from the American washing instruction. In this context, it seems to say that:

> A（を画面に）入れこみ　B（を映す）
>   (show / focus on) B, A within (the screen)

As Japanese is a verb-final language, the composition `N + V + N` usually doesn't form a valid construction other than relative clauses, or the reading-out of math formulae (3 たす 4).